# If $\frac{a(26.273)^b}{a(27.165)^b}=1.0065809$, find the values of $a$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help, I'm stuck in this problem:

> Find the values of $a$ and $b$:
>   $$\frac{a(26.273)^b}{a(27.165)^b}=1.0065809$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The way you wrote it, it looks like $a$ cancels, so could be anything

Comment: You cannot find the value of $a$ because it cancels. Concerning $b$ write your quotient under the form $(26..../27...)^k=1.006....$ and take the logarithm.

Comment: and having this equation $$o.9671636^b=1.0065809$$ whats next?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: how is this related to ordinary-differential-equations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{a(26.273)^b}{a(27.165)^b}=1.0065809$

the $a$'s cancel out:

$\frac{(26.273)^b}{(27.165)^b}=1.0065809$

$\left(\frac{26.273}{27.165}\right)^b=1.0065809$

$b=\log_\frac{26.273}{27.165}1.0065809\approx -482.95363$

$a=$anything except $0$

Comment: $\log_\frac{26.273}{27.165}$ ?! I have never ever used such a base ! If you are supposed to give good advices, don't give this one. From $\left(\frac{26.273}{27.165}\right)^b=1.0065809 \ \iff \ 0.967163^b=1.0065809$, take the natural logarithm ($\ln$) of LHS and RHS giving $b \ln 0.967163= \ln 1.0065809$ giving $b=\ln(...)/\ln(...)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie So a logarithm can't have fractional bases? Btw, I'm quite new to this is because I am only in middle school grade level(the eighth grade).

Comment: Yes, it can : it is very uncommun (but not forbidden !) that the base is $<1$. See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) where the plots in paragraph "Particular Bases" show that logarithm functions with base $<1$ (they take the example of $b=0.5$) are decreasing instead of increasing... Generaly speaking,I advise you to use one of the three categories of useful $\log_b$ functions : base $b=e$, base $b=2$ and base $b=10$ and not use other ones.